# how to turn my D-Link modem into a bridge/repeater for my USB 3G dongle?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, modem, dongle

I have a usb 3g dongle and a D-Link modem.
I like to know how to convert my d-link wifi modem as wifi transmitter for the data from usb dongle.

i.e. Internet connection source as my USB dongle amd wifi broadband modem as wifi transmitter.

Comment: What model is your D-Link modem? Your answer is dependent on how what hardware you use.

Comment: DLink <dsl-2730U> is my model

Comment: I confirmed your model can be used in bridge mode: http://setuprouter.com/router/dlink/dsl-2730u/manual-1648.pdf ... Now follow the link above (since this post is a duplicate) on how to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [DSL-2730U can be run in bridge mode](http://setuprouter.com/router/dlink/dsl-2730u/manual-1648.pdf) according the manual:

[image: wireless bridge]